# Migrating from Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob to Azure.Storage.Blobs - directory concepts missing

Tags: azure-storage

These are great guides for migrating between the different versions of NuGet package:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Storage.Blobs_12.6.0/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/README.md

https://elcamino.cloud/articles/2020-03-30-azure-storage-blobs-net-sdk-v12-upgrade-guide-and-tips.html

However I am struggling to migrate the following concepts in my code:

```
// Return if a directory exists:
container.GetDirectoryReference(path).ListBlobs().Any();
```

where `GetDirectoryReference` is not understood and there appears to be no direct translation.

Also, the concept of a `CloudBlobDirectory` does not appear to have made it into `Azure.Storage.Blobs` e.g.

```cs
private static long GetDirectorySize(CloudBlobDirectory directoryBlob) {
    long size = 0;

    foreach (var blobItem in directoryBlob.ListBlobs()) {
        if (blobItem is BlobClient)
            size += ((BlobClient) blobItem).GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;

        if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
            size += GetDirectorySize((CloudBlobDirectory) blobItem);
    }

    return size;
}
```

where `CloudBlobDirectory` does not appear anywhere in the API.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as physical directories or folders in Azure Blob Storage. The directories you sometimes see are part of the blob (e.g. `folder1/folder2/file1.txt`). The [List Blobs requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) allows you to add a prefix and delimiter in a call, which are used by the Azure Portal and Azure Data Explorer to create a visualization of folders. As example prefix `folder1/` and delimiter `/` would allow you to see the content as if folder1 was opened.

That's exactly what happens in your code. The `GetDirectoryReference()` adds a prefix. The `ListBlobs()` fires a request and `Any()` checks if any items return.

For V12 the command that'll allow you to do the same would be [GetBlobsByHierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet) and its async version. In your particular case where you only want to know if any blobs exist in the directory a [GetBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet) with prefix would also suffice.

Comment: But CloudBlobDirectory was part of the old api. Is your answer there is no equivalent in the new api?

Comment: My answer is that `GetBlobsByHierarchy` is the equivalent although it requires you to define a few more parameters yourself, which I explained in the post.